# Help what font is this?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Hey guys i need some help, exactly what font is this? [image]

Comment: i don't know what font is it but you can try using this site:
https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: Hi! We have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 2):

It's a drawing. It's made using Proxima Nova OR Proxima Soft font or both and masking or cutting parts off from some letters, editing the roundness of the endings with path editing tools and possibly adding a stroke to make the letters a little bolder.

[image]

[image]

Proxima Soft is a little too round here and there and Proxima Nova hasn't roundings at all.

The overall font shape matches as well as your fuzzy image allows to compare (by layering the font sample and your image in Photoshop with blending mode difference)

[image]